# Python 3.7 datetime format mismatch

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to parse this date string `July 30, 2018 11:59 PM PDT` in Python 3 using the `datetime.strptime` function.

After reading all of the documentation on the different directives available to use for date formatting, I came up with this format:

`%B %d, %Y %I:%M %p %Z`

For some reasons this continues to produce a ValueError saying that the date string doesn't conform to the provided format.

Unless there's something I'm missing, I don't know why this isn't working. Any ideas/help?

Comment: PDT isn't a recognized time zone name. You'll probably need to use [pyzt](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Related discussion: https://bugs.python.org/issue22377